# How to transpose values in this table into a specific format based on some specific logics?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a T-SQL query which returns the following output, stored in the database as `Table1`:

```
Id     AdultCount  Adult1Age   C1-5  C6-12  C13-17
---------------------------------------------------
101       2           45         1     0      0
102       1           36         0     0      0
103       2           40         0     2      1
```

I need to write a T-SQL query with the following logic:

1. column `Adult1Age` provides the age for 1 adult; in the case there are more than 1 adult, the remaining adults will have the existing `Adult1Age` minus 2 (that is, in the case of ID 101, the other adult will have Age = 45-2 = 43)
2. columns `C1-5`, `C6-12`, `C13-17` provide the counts of children for each of these age groups. That is, `C1-5` represents the count of children between 1 and 5 years. I will use the lower limit and upper limit of the category to compute the average age (mid-point) of the child. Thus, If I have 1 under C1-5, that child will have Age = (1+5)/2 = 3

   If we look at ID 103, it means we have we have 2 children of 9 years and 1 child of 15 years.

Now, I need a T-SQL query running on Table1 to return the following output:

```
Id     Age
----------
101    45
101    43
101     3
102    36
103    40
103    38
103     9
103     9
103    15
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following:

```
declare @tab table (Id int, AdultCount int, AdultAge int, [C1-5] int, [C6-12] int, [C13-17] int)
insert into @tab
select 101,2,45,1,0,0
union
select 102,1,36,0,0,0
union
select 103,2,40,0,2,1

select * from @tab

declare @t table (Id int)
insert into @t select distinct Id from @tab

while ((select count(1) from @t) > 0)
begin
    declare @Id int = (select top 1 Id from @t)
    declare @age_tab table (Id int, Age int)
    declare @cage1 smallint = 3, @cage2 smallint = 9, @cage3 smallint = 15
    declare @i_a int = (select AdultCount from @tab where Id = @Id)
    declare @i_c1 int = (select [C1-5] from @tab where Id = @Id)
    declare @i_c2 int = (select [C6-12] from @tab where Id = @Id)
    declare @i_c3 int = (select [C13-17] from @tab where Id = @Id)
    declare @age int = (select AdultAge from @tab where Id = @Id)

    while (@i_a>1)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, (@age - 2)
        set @age-=2
        set @i_a-=1
    end

    while (@i_c1>0)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, @cage1
        set @i_c1-=1
    end
    while (@i_c2>0)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, @cage2
        set @i_c2-=1
    end
    while (@i_c3>0)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, @cage3
        set @i_c3-=1
    end
    insert into @age_tab select Id, AdultAge from @tab where Id = @Id

    delete @t where Id = @Id
end

select * from @age_tab
order by Id, age desc
```

HTH!

Thanks.